# Concurrent access: volatility and synchronization

Tags: java

I have been reading through quite a few posts about synchronized and volatile keywords/idoms and I think I understood correctly how they work and when should they be used. However, I still have some doubts on something I'm trying to do. Consider the following:

```
public class X {
  private volatile int x;

  public X(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }  

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }
}
```

The one above is pretty much straightfoward and thread-safe. Now consider the same class X with the following changes:

```
public class X {
  private volatile int x;
  private volatile Y yObj;
  private volatile boolean active;

  public X(Y yObj) {
    this.yObj = yObj;
    active = false;
    x = yObj.getY();
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    if (active) throw new IllegalStateException()
    if (!yObj.isValid(x)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.x = x;  
  }

  public void setY(Y yObj) {
    if (active) throw new IllegalStateException();
    this.yObj = yObj;
    x = yObj.getY();
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public Y getY() {
    return yObj;
  } 

  public synchronized void start() {
     if (active) throw new IllegalStateException();
     /*
      * code that performs some initializations and condition checking runs here
      * does not depend on x and yObj
      * might throw an exception
      */
      active = true;
  }

  public synchronized void stop() {
      if (!active) throw new IllegalStateException();
      /* some code in the same conditions of the comments in the start()
       * method runs here
       */
      active = false;
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
  }
}
```

Now, I declared `yObj` as `volatile` to ensure that every single thread sees the same object reference when changed by calling `setY(Y)` method. The idea of the `Y` class is to provide the `X` class a set (in this example just one) of reference values when calling the setters of a `X` object. The questions are:

1. Can `x` still be declared as `volatile` and ensure common visibility for all threads or further synchronization is required?
2. The idea is to make all objects of class `Y` immutable. So, I assume that all its fields must be immutable as well. What would be the best way to make `Y` user implementable but as the same time be thread-safe? An abstract class that implements the thread-safe mechanisms and then it can be extendable? Currently, `Y` is an interface with getter methods that can be implemented, of course, not thread-safe.
3. Is the start/stop mechanism implemented correctly from the perspective of concurrent access?

Comment: `setY` for example uses 2 unsynchronized operations. `getX()` might not see the new `x` but the new `yObj`. That's potentially not threadsafe. Also `setX` and `setY` are not safe, you can end up with the x from setX but the y from setY

Comment: @zapl you're right, missed that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your problem is that `private volatile Y yObj;` only makes the `yObj` reference `volatile`, not its contents.

When you later do `x = yObj.getY();` you may be requesting access to a non-volatile variable which could, theoretically be thread-unsafe as a result.

Making `yObj` immutable may help but enforcing that would be difficult.

Your start/stop mechanism looks fine but I would use an `AtomicBoolean`, drop the synchronisation and use `if(active.compareAndSet(false, true) { ...` or similar.

Comment: yes, I know that declaring yObj as volatile only makes the reference volatile and not its contents. Regarding the contents that would be question #2. Would be that hard to enforce it? If Y does only provide simple getters and setters, wouldn't that it be straight forward by just declaring its members volatile? The start/stop mechanism may throw and exception, so, in that case, the flag mustn't change its state. Calling compareAndSet(), I believe it does changing its state right way, even before evaluating preconditions, no?